# Scale up image inside layer in PSD loses quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, png, android

I'm an Android developer who knows not much about getting assets (pngs) from a psd or ai file to multiple resolutions that the Android platform needs.

With Inkscape it's pretty straightforward. Foreach vector or image I need, I just export it to PNG for multiple resolutions.

However a client sent a psd file and I don't really know if scaling up and down images or layers inside the psd loses quality. I know that ai files are vectors so there is no quality lose, but with psd files I'm not sure.

Is it okay if I scale up and down images inside layers on the psd files for multiple resolutions without quality lose? Or I have to ask the client to send me an ai file?

Thanks!

Comment: It *completely* depends upon the nature of the layer. Vector or shape layers, no problem. Raster layers could be a problem (although Photoshop does a decent job of interpolating within itself).

Comment: I will try to know what type of layer is with Gimp and will come back to you

Comment: Do you know how to check it?

Comment: Not with Gimp, no.

Comment: If you load a PSD file in GIMP (2.8 and earlier, and current development versions, too), the answer is rather easy: it is a raster layer.

Comment: So, a psd file almost always contains raster layers, right?

Comment: It depends on the case of course. But I would ask client if he takes the responsibility for the quality of the provided graphics or you do. And depending on the answer either he provides the images of appropriate sizes or you rescale. You know, sometimes "just rescaling" is not enough and in that particular case somebody should decide what to do: either to redraw the image or take another one or something else.